# Hidden column significance in table?

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [metadata for determining unsed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214136/metadata-for-determining-unsed-columns)
>   [How can you tell which columns are unused in ALL_TAB_COLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949226/how-can-you-tell-which-columns-are-unused-in-all-tab-cols)

Hi,
I have to fetch only used column names from all_tab_cols only not unsused ,may  i know 
hidden_column column is  marked 'Y' for unused_column only or their some other reasons also.

Comment: Is this not reall the same as your earlier question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214136/metadata-for-determining-unsed-columns/3218747#3218747

Answer (score 1):

In 11g, function-based indexes are implemented as a virtual column (i.e. (column1 + column2)) and are marked as a hidden column.